# Croppie.js is also selecting Videos while browsing files for Images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, croppie

I am using Croppie.js for cropping and uploading images on my site. However, I found that while browsing for images, it also shows video and other format files and is even selecting it. I searched the [documentation](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) for the solution but could not find it. It does says in documentation about the formats supporting jpeg and png but that is only at the result. I did not find a way to restrict displaying video files. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
  // Croppie
  var resize = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    enableOrientation: true,
    viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' }
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        type: 'circle' //square
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 325,
        height: 325
    }
  });
  $('#image').on('change', function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        resize.croppie('bind',{
          url: e.target.result
        }).then(function(){
          // console.log('jQuery bind complete');
        });
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  });
  $('.btn-upload-image').on('click', function (ev) {
    resize.croppie('result', {
      type: 'canvas',
      size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (img) {
      var imgval = $('#image').val();
      var dataString = {
        image: img,
        imgval: imgval
      };
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        url: "processes/avatar.php",
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function(){
          $('.message').hide();
          $(".btn-upload-image").html('Please wait...');
        },
        success: function (json) {
          $(".message").html(json.msg).fadeIn();
          $('#preview-image').attr('src', json.preview);
          $(".btn-upload-image").html('Upload');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I got the solution! Holy crap, just within a minute after posting the question. No worries, the answer will help future searchers.

HTML5 supports `accept` attribute to define what type of file should be accepted. I simply put the in the code this way:

```
<input type="file" id="image" accept="image/*">
```